# Уйма: конкретное число или..?

Tags: этимология

"Уйма" — значит, очень много. Но откуда это слово взялось? Оно обозначало когда-то определенное число, как "тьма", или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фасмер считает, что из диалекта: у́йма -диал. также "дремучий лес", костром.(Даль) - то есть очень много деревьев.

Образовалось  от у и jęti, jьmǫ (см. возьму́, взять); см. Преобр. I, 270. По мнению последнего, первонач. "столько, сколько можно взять".

Comment: Глагол уняться/уймешься как-нибудь тут соотносится?

Comment: По корню да, тоже от взять(ст-слав имать),  jęti,  только там приставка со значением уменьшения, а в "уйме" со значением "в" - вбирать. И даже внимать, внимание от этого же корня, приставки меняются, меняется смысл, зачастую значения вообще расходятся, а корень тот же.

Comment: А почему это слово не считают заимствованным из восточно-европейской языков? В готском, например, есть слово iumjo - толпа.

Comment: Не знаю, я не специалист в германских языках.Наши учёные утверждают, что уйма- общеславянское.История этого понятия в литературу проникла вместе с книгой "Опыты областного великорусского языка", которые были напечатаны в 1852 году. В лексиконе писателя С-Щедрина также обнаружено употребление этого слова. Поначалу слово употреблялось только в  Костромской обл., произошло из местного диалекта -  "дремучий лес"(В. Даль). Потом стало значить "немного" ( с польск. "убыток и ущерб"), потом - "много".http://fb.ru/article/437552/uyma---eto-skolko-etimologiya-upotreblenie-i-znachenie-slova